# How to copy a file given a URL using Javascript during the copy event?

Tags: javascript

Code is simple I have a copy event.

```js
// in reality this blob is arbitrary it could be even an executable
// the url doesn't have to be blob but it could be blob
const url: string = "blob://...";
document.addEventListener('copy', async function (e) {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url, false); // Synchronous request because it will not work with async
      // xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
      // commented out because it will be rejected and crash the code
      xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
      xhr.send(null);
    
      if (xhr.status 

=== 200) {
    // yes I know this isn't binary but there's nothing I can do since responseType arrayBuffer is not allowed hence both response and responseText are strings
    const binary = xhr.responseText;

    // this is corrupted anyway
    const dataUri = `data:${xhr.getResponseHeader('content-type')};base64,${btoa(binary)}`;

    // Set the data URI to the clipboard alongside the copied text
    const text = window.getSelection().toString();
    e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', text);
    e.clipboardData.setData('text/uri-list', dataUri);

    console.log(dataUri);

    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

No matter what I try it simply will refuse to work, it seems to be impossible; mainly because I cannot create the data uri from the request, and because I am not allowed to use async.

This code was also tried, just for an example, where I pass the code as dataURI just to test.

```js
e.preventDefault();
  const image = await fetch(url).then(response => response.blob());
  const data = await blobToDataURL(image);
  const text = new Blob(['Cute sleeping kitten'], {type: 'text/plain'});
  const html = new Blob([`<img src=${data}>`], {type: 'text/html'});
  const item = new ClipboardItem({
    'text/plain': text,
    "text/html": html,
  });
  await navigator.clipboard.write([item]);
```

Doesn't work either, during the paste event, e.clipboardData.getData("text/plain") or "text/html" are both empty.

It does really make it seem as if copying files from blobs is currently not supported.

These files do not exist in a server of any kind, so the URL is useless in any other context, in most cases they are blobs: that reside locally in indexedDB, but that's beyond the point; the point is, server based solutions are not useful.

Answer (score 0):

After asking ChatGPT for a while and figuring out potential solutions, I now realized that the problem was the security system of the browser while I was debugging completely obliterated the information I was trying to copy, which means that debugging was causing the bug with the last piece of code as proposed using the navigator.clipboard.

So since you can't trust the debugger, nor even console.logs at times, the last code:

```js
e.preventDefault();
  const image = await fetch(url).then(response => response.blob());
  const data = await blobToDataURL(image);
  const text = new Blob(['Cute sleeping kitten'], {type: 'text/plain'});
  const html = new Blob([`<img src=${data}>`], {type: 'text/html'});
  const item = new ClipboardItem({
    'text/plain': text,
    "text/html": html,
  });
  await navigator.clipboard.write([item]);
```

Does in fact work, but only if you don't try to debug it; I can't fully tell why but it may be related to some security policy and self XSS attack where the contents of the clipboard may be used maliciously, which in my case meant debugging was not possible.